# Can a wizard cast Permanency on another caster's spell effect?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Let's say a sorcerer casts *arcane sight* on herself. Would another caster be allowed to cast *permanency* on the *arcane sight* buff? At first I thought it was a no-brainer, but the charts in the PHB make it sound like cooperative use of *permanency* is not allowed, and that the caster of *permanency* must also be the caster of the other spells.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Not for the 'Self Only' spells

*You* cast [*permanency*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#permanency)

The part *prior* to the first table says

> *You* can make the following spells permanent in regard to *yourself*.
>   [Emphasis mine]

Plus, following the table, the text reiterates

> *You* cast the desired spell and then follow it with the permanency spell. You cannot cast these spells on other creatures.

This is rules text, not a table; the table follows.

Plus, if it were a table only, the rules text would only supersede it if there were a conflict (there's not).

---

### But for the rest...

For the other spells on the list, the source of the original spell is immaterial, it appears that the spell must merely be in effect on the target

> In addition to personal use, permanency can be used to make the following spells permanent on yourself, another creature, or an object (as appropriate)...